# Spark : Can't set table properties start with "spark.sql" to hive external table while creating

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive

Env : linux (spark-submit xxx.py)

Target database : Hive

We used to use beeline to execute hql, but now we try to run the hql through pyspark and faced some issue when tried to set table properties while creating the table.

**SQL**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE example.a(
  column_a string)

TBLPROPERTIES (
  'discover.partitions'='true',  
  'spark.sql.sources.schema.numPartCols'='1', 
  'spark.sql.sources.schema.numParts'='1', 
  'spark.sql.sources.schema.part.0'='{"type":"struct","fields":[{"name":"column_a","type":"string","nullable":true,"metadata":{}}]}', 
  'spark.sql.sources.schema.partCol.0'='received_utc_date_partition');
```

**Error message**

```
Hive - ERROR - Cannot persist
example.a into Hive metastore as table property
keys may not start with 'spark.sql.': [spark.sql.sources.schema.partCol.0, spark.sql.sources.schema.numParts,
spark.sql.sources.schema.numPartCols, spark.sql.sources.schema.part.0];
```

In line 130-147 in [spark source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/hive/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/HiveExternalCatalog.scala) it seems that it prevent all table properties that start with "spark.sql"

Not sure if I did it wrong or there's another way to set up the table properties for hive table.
Any kinds of suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I just stumbled upon this error

Comment: @lealvcon did you find a solution to this? I got this same error now.

Answer (score 0):

Do not try to set table properties, just set `format("Hive")` and the table properties can be automatic updated, like this:

```
Dataset.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).format("Hive").saveAsTable(tableNmae);
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more about the root cause?